# Volume of Paraboloid inside Cylinder

Tags: integration, analytic-geometry

A paraboloid is inside a cylinder as follows:
[image]

The goal is to prove that the volume of the paraboloid is exactly one-half that of the cylinder. So, I did the proper integration required, and got $\pi ph^2$. But what is $p$?

Comment: Hint: $(h, r)$ should be a point on the parabola projected on the plane. That is, $r^2 = 2 p h$.

Comment: That helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meantime, let's mention that for the parabola $y^2=px$, $p$ is the distance between the focus $F$ and your directrix $d$ called **focal parameter**. The paraboloid of the figure has equation $x=p(y^2+z^2)$ (where $z$ is the axis coming out of the page) and is a surface of revolution about the $y$ axis of the section of the paraboloid $y^2=2px$.